# Rails get most sold products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, sorting, activerecord

I would like to return *N* number most sold products, my models:

**Order**

```
has_many :order_items
```

**OrderItem**

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
quantity
```

I've something like this up to now, but it's not including quantity and wrong, any help would be great.

**product.rb**

```
def self.popular
  products = OrderItem.group(:product_id).count
  ids = products.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
  where(id: ids)
end
```

**Example:**

```
[#<OrderItem:0x007fa522727328 id: 1, order_id: 1, product_id: 1, quantity: 3>,
 #<OrderItem:0x007fa5227270a8 id: 2, order_id: 2, product_id: 5, quantity: 4>,
 #<OrderItem:0x007fa522726d88 id: 3, order_id: 2, product_id: 9, quantity: 9>]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[#<Product:0x007fa5298f9a28 id: 3, title: 'MacBook air'>,
 #<Product:0x007fa5298f9b28 id: 5, title: 'Iphone 6s'>,
 #<Product:0x007fa5298f9c28 id: 1, title: 'Nexus 5'>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replaced the line

```
ids = products.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
```

with

```
ids = products.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse.map(&:first)
```

I tried it in console and it works well.

**UPDATE:**

Order by sum of `quantity` field:

```
products = OrderItem.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
ids = products.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse.map(&:first)
```

**Update2:**

Add this method in your `product` model:

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  order_by = ["case"]
  ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
    order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
  end
  order_by << "end"
  order(order_by.join(" "))
end
```

Then:

```
products = OrderItem.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
ids = products.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse.map(&:first)
where(id: ids)..order_by_ids(ids)
```

Comment: but it doesn't take in account `quantity` field and the order in not correct

Comment: Are you going to order by count of association or sum of quantity?

Comment: thanks, it's almost working, but its not sorted properly now, any suggestions?